# Upload video to App using Appcelerator

Tags: video, upload, titanium, appcelerator

I am attempting to upload video from device (both Android and iOS) to server. But how can I upload those files video?

If I upload video file without streaming it. Too hard to handle and it will cause time out when upload video have large size. I use Titanium/Appcelerator to upload file.

Who have solution for this case please give me a provision. I refer that can stream video to small piece and transfer it to server. At server, I will decode it and gather it and store to server.

Thanks all.

Comment: Your question is to general to be answered. There are thousands of ways for uploading a video from a device. Please be more specific about what you want to do and what your actual problem is.

Comment: @BastianVoigt : currently, i can upload video use Titanium.Network.HTTPClient to send whole file to Server. But when i work with large file, it cause timeout. So i want to know we have other ways to upload video to server ?

Answer (score 0):

While the timeout problem is a server-side problem and you could perhaps change the timeout time, there is a tutorial about "chunked uploads" at https://lowb1rd.github.io/002-chunked-uploads-with-titanium.html using Ti.Buffer/Ti.Stream